# Get the first empty row in multidimensionnal array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a question about a function where I'm trying to get a first look at a multidimensional array.

To explain my problem: In a sheet, I manage my roadmap with projects. A project is composed by 4 rows where I have some information (Project Name, Estimated Team, Timeline ...).
And In my timeline, I need to retrieve the first empty rows in multiple arrays (the first non empty is the startDate).
The problem, I have 4 teams in this multidimensional array, and (for example), the start date can be in the 1st team array for the project A, but the start date can be also in the 3rd team array for the project B.

In my function, I'm trying to get to the start date, but my first step is to check the first array ... (projectRange and after in the code)
So ... I think the best way should be check every rows in the first column, and continue like this to the getLastColumn, right?
So, how can I manage my Loop with this way?

```
function findLastRow(column) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(roadmapSS);

  var startRow = 11;
  var startCol = 11;
  var dataLength = sheet.getLastRow()-(startRow+2);

  var rangeData = sheet.getRange(startRow, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  var dataValues = rangeData.getValues();

  var projectsList = rangeData.getValues();
  var projectDatas = {};
  var projectRange = null;
  var projectName = null;
  var projectPlan = {};
  var realStart = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i+=4) {
    projectDatas = projectsList[i];

    var step = startRow+i;
    var realStartRange = startRow+i+1

    for (var j = 0; j < 1; j+=4) {
      projectName = projectDatas[j];
    }

    projectRange = ([step, startCol, 4, sheet.getLastColumn()]).toString();
    var projectPlan = sheet.getRange(step, startCol, 4, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

    for (var k = 0; k < projectPlan.length; ++k) {
      realStart = projectPlan[k];

      for (var l = 0; l < realStart.length; ++l) {
        if (realStart[l] != '') {  
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    //sheet.getRange(realStartRange, 2).setValue(columnToLetter([l]))
    console.log(projectName, [l], columnToLetter([l]));
  }    
}
```

In fact, i'm trying to get the first column of B in this example (because it's the first non empty occurence :

```
var projectTimeline = [
  ['','','A','A','','A'],
  ['','B','B','','B',''],
  ['','','','C','C',''],
  ['','','','','D','D']
]
```

Comment: can you show an example of a data set and what it should return?

Comment: @LioraHaydont I'm update my topic with an example where i'm trying to get the column (and the specific row) of the first "B"

Comment: Why are you checking every 4th row? If the first row you check is row 11 then `for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i+=4)` will check rows `11, 15, 19` etc. because your initial dataset is `projectList[row][column]`, so you end up doing `projectDatas = projectsList[0];` then `projectDatas = projectsList[4];` then `projectDatas = projectsList[8];` and so on

Comment: I'm checking every 4th row in the first loop to find projects because a project is compose by 4 rows. After that, I have my project and the range of timeline associated. This is in the second loop I would like to get the first non empty column/row (the first B in my first example). And in this second loop I'm checking every rows. But it doesn't work, the function get the last "D" instead of the first "B".

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution :
I throughed the column first, and then the row. It worked, I founded the column :)

```
function findFirstDate (timeline) {
  for (var col = 0; col < timeline[0].length; col++) {
      for (var row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
        if (timeline[row][col] != '') {
          return [col];
        }
      }
    }
}
```